# SqlQuery is not a definition in EF Core Dbset()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am quite new to using EF Core so I might have some misconceptions but can I check why `SqlQuery` is not a proper method for `Dbset()`?

Here are some snippets of my code just to show how I set up the `DbContext`:

**Model**

```
public class CSVFile
{
    [Key]
    public int RecordId { get; set; } = 0;

    public double CO2 { get; set; } = 0.0;
    public double ambTemp { get; set; } = 0.0;
    public double relativeHumidity { get; set; } = 0.0;
}
```

**Db Context**

```
public class CSVProxyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        var connectionString = string.Format(@"Data Source=name;Initial Catalog=CSVProxyDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

    public DbSet<CSVFileProxy> CSVFileProxys { get; set; }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CSVProxyDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddScoped<ICSVService, CSVService>();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }
```

**Snippet of controller**

```
public class CSVController : Controller
{
    ICSVService _csvService = null;
    List<CSVFile> _records = new List<CSVFile>();

    List<CSVFileProxy> _proxyRecords = new List<CSVFileProxy>();
    private readonly CSVProxyDbContext _proxydb;

    public CSVController(ICSVService csvService, CSVProxyDbContext proxydb)
    {
        _csvService = csvService;
        _proxydb = proxydb;
    }

    public JsonResult DeleteCSVProxy(List<CSVFileProxy> proxyRecords)
    {
        _proxydb.CSVFileProxys.RemoveRange(_proxydb.CSVFileProxys);              
        _proxydb.CSVFileProxys.SqlQuery("DBCC CHECKIDENT('CSVProxyDbContextConnection', RESEED, 0)");                                                          
        _proxydb.SaveChanges();                      
        return Json(null);
    }
}
```

I am trying to reset the `[Key] RecordId`'s count within the Db whenever `DeleteCSVProxy()` is called. But since  EF Core does not recognize `SqlQuery()` for some reason, I am not too sure how I should proceed with this.

Error:

> Error CS1061
> 'DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlCommand' and no accessible extension method 'ExecuteSqlCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Could you check if it works with  _proxydb.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("your query"); this is how to send an udate delete etc
If it is a "select" you can use _proxydb.CSVFileProxy.FromSqlRaw("your query");

Comment: Erm.. You're using EF Core but have linked to a tut about EF6. Are you aware that they are vastly different things?

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard, sorry I wasn't aware. Hi @dimmits, thks for the suggestion but it is still not a definition for `Dbset()`. Can I check how I could implement `DBCC` with `ASP.NET EF Core 5`? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Hey @CaiusJard, thanks for the redirect; I tried doing some extra digging too but could not find an implementation of DBCC using Fromsqlraw/FromSqlInterpolated for EF Core 5. Do you think you could advise? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'd be something like `context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DBCC CHECKIDENT('CSVProxyDbContextConnection', RESEED, 0)");` - ie something you just execute at the database level  rather then in conjunction with any table set

Comment: The Fromxxx methods on a set are so you can turn a raw query into a bunch of entity objects and also attach other parts to them using normal linq

Answer (score 1):

Use of `SqlQuery` - looks like youre following a EF6 (or maybe EF5, in confusion with EFCore5) tutorial and trying to apply its advice to EF Core; they're quite different animals

EF Core 5 version would look like

```
_proxydb.CSVFileProxys.ExecuteSqlRaw($"DBCC CHECKIDENT('CSVProxyDbContextConnection', RESEED, 0)");
```

Or if you're using some parameters:

```
_proxydb.CSVFileProxys.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"DBCC CHECKIDENT('{someParam}', RESEED, {anotherParam})");
```

**Important**: use `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` if you pass an interpolated string with parameters embedded; EFCore will pick it apart and turn the {..} into proper SQL Parameters. `ExecuteRaw`ing it will NOT do this, C# will form the SQL string and it will NOT be parameterized.. And that is Very Bad

In earlier (pre-3) EF Core versions you just had one method `ExecuteSql` which suffered some problems; if you didn't put the SQL format str straight into the method you opened up injection attacks:

```
//acceptable
_proxydb.CSVFileProxys.ExecuteSql($"DBCC CHECKIDENT('{someParam}', RESEED, {anotherParam})");

//not good
var sql = $"DBCC CHECKIDENT('{someParam}', RESEED, {anotherParam})";
_proxydb.CSVFileProxys.ExecuteSql(sql);
```

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard, thanks for the for explanations! However, I am still curious as to why DbSet() does not recognize the `ExecuteSqlRaw` method. Also, can I check that `CSVProxyDbContextConnection` is meant to be the connection string? I.e.,   `"ConnectionStrings": {
    "CSVProxyDbContextConnection": "Data Source=sam-126;Initial Catalog=CSVProxyDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },` in `appsettings.json`?